# Definition of a differentiable curve on a manifold.

Tags: derivatives, differential-geometry, manifolds, curves

Let me just set up some very standard notions. (I am working from the lecture series International Winter School on Gravity and Light 2015 on youtube)

$\textbf{Setup:}$
Given a d-dimensional topological manifold $(M,\mathcal{O}_M,\mathcal{A})$, here $M$ is the set, $\mathcal{O}_M$ the topology on $M$, and $\mathcal{A}$ is the associated atlas. Let $\rho:\mathbb{R}\to M$ be some path.

---

$\textbf{Definition:}$
The manifold is said to be smooth if the atlas $\mathcal{A}$ contains charts which are $C^\infty$ compatiable, that is two charts $(x,U_x),(y,U_y)$ are said to be $C^\infty$-compatible if $U_x\cap U_y=\emptyset$ or
$$ y\circ x^{-1}: x(U_x\cap U_y)\to y(U_x\cap U_y),~\qquad\text{and}\qquad x\circ y^{-1}: y(U_x\cap U_y)\to x(U_x\cap U_y), $$
are $C^\infty$ (from $\mathbb{R}^d\to \mathbb{R}^d$).

---

In the youtube series, the professor introduces notion of the velocity of a curve $\rho$, he starts by assuming the curve is $C^1$. So it seems like before understanding what velocity is I need to know what it means for the curve $\rho$ to be $C^1$, he doesnt seem to explicitly define this notion, can anyone help?

Comment: $C^1$ means that the function which describe the curve (in some fixed choice of smooth coordinates for the manifold) can be differentiated at least once. If you look at the definition of the velocity, it involved taking the derivative once, so it's simply not defined unless these functions are differentiable

Comment: @DavidSheard so for each chart $x\circ \rho$ is $C^1$ function from $\mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}^d$?

Comment: The image of $\rho$ is $M$, and the domain of $x$ is $\mathbb{R}^d$, so the composition $x\circ \rho$ does not make sense. Instead define the path by maps $\mathbb{R}\to U_x$ which have to be $C^1$, and whose composition with $x$ yield $\rho$.

Comment: $C^1$ usually also means that the derivative is itself continuous.

Comment: @DavidSheard if $x$ is a chart then the domain of $x$ is not $\mathbb{R}^d$. The composition $x\circ \rho$ certainly does make sense as a function from $\rho^{-1}(U_x)\to \mathbb{R}^d$. Note $U_x \subset M$.

Comment: @CrackedBauxite I know but what does the derivative mean when $M$ is a manifold.

Comment: Ah Ok, the way you set up notation in your question indicated to me that $x$ was a function $\mathbb{R}^d\superset U_x\to M$, whatever the notation, $C^1$ means you can differentiate the functions which define the path at least once. As @CrackedBauxite points out, in particular this means that those derivatives will be continuous functions

Comment: @DavidSheard what do you mean by 'the functions' exactly?

Comment: The components of $\rho$ expressed in the coordinates of the chart you've chosen

Comment: Look at the definition of velocity in the youtube videos you are watching. It involves taking the first derivative of a function/functions - those are the functions I'm talking about, and those are the ones which must bet $C^1$